# multiple file uploading with other data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to upload multiple files and store them in a folder and get other data.
html file

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='formtest' method='POST' >
<input type='text' name='report_name' id='report_name'/>
<input type='file' id='multiFiles' name='files[]' class='multiupload' 
multiple='multiple'/>
<button type='button'>Submit</buton>
```

js file

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("files");
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if(elem[i].value != ''){                  
        names.push(elem[i].value);
    }
}
tmpData = new FormData();
tmpData.append('files',form_data);
tmpData.append('report_name',document.getElementById('report_name').value );        
AJAX("treatment.php", 0, tmpData);
```

php file

```
echo count($_FILES['files']['name']);
```

I tried this code but this is not working.

Comment: Please provide full code.

Comment: This is pointless, why don't you just use the form id on submit as `FormData(this)`and call Ajax. That'll pass all multiple files to php. Also the class of the file input is `multiupload` not files. You really need tutorials before embarking on such module

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("files");
```

In your code, file type input doesn't seem to have "files" class so you can't get it this way. Try

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("multiupload");
```

Instead